# How to view LibGDX logs running on iOS using Android Studio?

Tags: ios, android-studio, libgdx

I have a project using LibGDX for Android and iOS. I've already deployed on both OS. To see Android logs I use Android Monitor/Logcat inside Android studio, but for iOS I don't know where to look if it's logging.

The line I'm using to push logs is:

```
Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Log message");
```

Is it possible to read those iOS logs inside Android Studio? Or do I need to look for them somehow in Xcode?

Comment: Are you using MOE or RoboVM?

Comment: I'm using RoboVM @Tenfour04

Comment: I haven't touched it in a year...but I think you're out of luck if you didn't get a RoboVM license before they shut down. Logging was a premium feature.

Comment: Oh, I read something about that. I have just started using it a week ago, so I don't have a license. Bad luck :(

Comment: I think the MOE backend supports it. Haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: I will try it. And if it does I post an answer.